# C# how to implement a loop with time step

Tags: c#, time

I need to implement a function that contains a loop of instructions that should run every .01 second is there a way to implement a loop(e.g for each time step) that can do that
thanks in advance

Comment: How precise do you need that to be? For example, suppose it runs 64 times a second instead of 100, is that acceptable? Suppose it runs 10003 times in 100 seconds, is that acceptable? Timer granularity might not be as precise as you need it to be; Windows is not a realtime operating system. You need to use special techniques if you need high precision timers.

Comment: please mark your question as answered

Answer (score 8):

You can use Timer class like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer(100);
t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // your loop
        }
    };

t.Start();
```

Comment: +1 for the example, although I also gave Robert +1 for having the answer first.

Comment: why this loop for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ??

Comment: It's a sample loop. It can be replaced by any kind of loop/code.

Comment: AS-CII: you're answer is more complete, though

Comment: Is the timer granularity really that good? It might be instructive to test this and see how many times per second you are actually getting called.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a recurring event using the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class.