# Timer Loop in c#, wait if code isn't completed

Tags: c#, loops, timer

I'm trying to implement a timer loop in c# (say each 30 miliseconds a piece of code should run). This isn't so hard, as others questions here in SO have already addressed this issue, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418820/implementing-a-loop-using-a-timer-in-c-sharp), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982694/c-sharp-how-to-implement-a-loop-with-time-step/3982733#3982733).

The trickiest part is that the piece of code can last more than the loop time. In this case I want to wait until it ends (not another 30 ms wait).

Example:

0 ms - First iteration: code completed in 20 ms.

30 ms - Second iteration: code isn't completed in time.

60 ms - wait second iteration code to end. Ended in total 41 ms.

71 ms - Third iteration: code completed in 15 ms.

101 ms - Fourth iteration: code completed in 22 ms.

And so on.

Should I use a Task and check if is completed?
What is a fair, elegant way of do that.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
After a couple of tries, this code seems to work with example code, lets see later with the production code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/cqmTzF

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, do you have examples?

Comment: Yes, I tried a bit more, and apparently got a working solution. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    public class PeriodicAction
    {
        private int _frequencyMs;
        private readonly Timer _timer;
        private bool _enabled;

        public Action ActionMethod { get; private set; }

        public int FrequencyMs
        {
            get { return _frequencyMs; }
            set
            {
                _frequencyMs = value;
                _timer.Change(0, _frequencyMs);
            }
        }

        public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return _enabled; }
            set
            {
                _timer.Change(value ? 0 : Timeout.Infinite, _frequencyMs);
                _enabled = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

        public PeriodicAction(Action actionMethod, int frequencyMs)
        {
            this.ActionMethod = actionMethod;
            this._frequencyMs = frequencyMs;
            this._timer = new Timer(timerCallbackMethod, null, 0, frequencyMs);
        }

        private void timerCallbackMethod(object sender)
        {
            if (IsRunning) return;

            IsRunning = true;

            ActionMethod();
            _timer.Change(0, _frequencyMs);

            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to implement my code.